# How to handle a "no action required" HTTP response

Tags: .net, angular, http

I have an angular application. When a user logs in, the application sends a username/token pair off to an API route on a .NET backend.

If the username/token pair doesn't exist, the .NET application adds it to the database and returns a `Created()` response.

However, if the pair *does* exist (and it likely will), then no action is required and nothing is `Created()`. In this case, what response should I return?

Alternate solution: I could run two requests against the API, one `GET` to see if the user/tokan pair exists and then a `POST` request if it does not, but that isn't as efficient, requires nested promises and is generally not as pretty. Maybe preferable anyway?

Answer (score 3):

### RESTfull user sessions

Following on my previous answer (deleted now) but I thought I would share how I handle this case.

### POST => 201 created

If you want to always start a new user session you should send a `POST`. The server yields `201 created` if a new session can be started. It's up to you if there is a constraint on using duplicate tokens. This means, that the front-end only sends `POST` when it knows it's going to be a new session.

### PATCH => 204 no content

If you have a user/token pair and that can be used to identify a user session resource on the server. You just need to `PATCH` it to continue the session. If the patch is success the server can send `204`.

If the session is no longer valid. The server should yield `401 unauthorized` response.

### GET, EDIT

These requests yield a `403 forbidden` since user sessions can not be modified by the front-end.

Don't confuse user registration and user login with user sessions. Those are different RESTfull resources with different URL end points.

Comment: Point being, the application doesn't _know_ if the user/token pair exists until after it has sent the request.

Answer (score 2):

The response you want would be your choice as an API designer. I would probably do an Ok() response or NoContent() as long as the response isn't an error response.